# Problems with install Mrtg

Tags: windows, snmp, mrtg

Im trying to configure Mrtg on my Windows machine. I'm following the mrtg guide

**http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-nt-guide.en.html.**

but i get this:

```
perl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

when I enter this:

`perl mrtg`

I've tried to follow the youtube video too, but I get the same error.

Comment: Try no paste the text into your question instead of taking a screenshot. It will make helping you easier.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either failed to install `perl`, or failed to make it available in the %PATH% variable of your PC. Note the instruction saying

> You might want to make sure that the Perl binary directory is listed in your system path.

As for how to put a program into the path of a Windows machine, that's not very difficult to find with a bit of searching online.